# How can you add Index (for lookups) to existing Database in Entity Framework Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I read about the use of Guids for clustering indexes and its efficiency and I was wondering about clearing my whole database and starting from scratch (as it is a small project) but I think it's better if I try to add Indexes now.

Is it possible in my situation, with the following model:

```
public class Room
    {

        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DeviceId")]
        public Device Device { get; set; }
        public Guid? DeviceId { get; set; }

    }
```

and the following DBContext:

```
public LocationContext(DbContextOptions<LocationContext> options) : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
                .HasOne(r => r.Device)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.DeviceId)             
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
                .HasOne(r => r.Room)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.RoomId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        }
```

To add Indexes to my entities?

According to some articles I found I have to use [Fluent API to add Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes). So what I want to do is add a INT property to my Room entity(and Device) and use that as my Index to increase performance.

Can I just add a Int to my Properties called Index and configure FluentAPI like this:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
        .HasIndex(r => r.Index)
        .IsUnique();
```

Like I said, I want to know if doing this is the correct way and what happens with existing records in my database before committing any changes.

Comment: Using _sequential_ GUIDs as your clustered primary key is better than adding a secondary index, in most cases.  If this is SQL Server see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2012/06/25/good-page-splits-and-sequential-guid-key-generation/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2012/07/03/how-to-generate-sequential-guids-for-sql-server-in-net/